# MySQL: UPDATE trigger. Obtain the value of a column used in UPDATE's where clause if it fail to match any row?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update, where-clause

MySQL: In update trigger's body, can I obtain the value of a column that is specified in the `where` clause of the triggering query if the `wher`e clause does not match any rows at all?

I have to do the following, but NOT USING direct query such as ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE so on:

If I have:

```
UPDATE my_table SET idiotism_level=5 WHERE name='Pencho'
```

... and the where clause match NO ROWS, I'd want to automatically trigger an insertion of a row having `name='Pencho'` before the update, and then the `UPDATE` would presumably match, and work properly.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be make in a **RULE** in other database systems (PostgreSQL), that does not exists in MySQL. It's a Rule and not a trigger as you should analyse the query and not the result of the query.

But for MySQL you can make pre-query jobs by using [MySQL-Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html). You should be able to alter your update query and build an insert, By running some 'check row exists' extra query from the MySQL-Proxy (I'm not saying this is a nice solution, but if you have no way to make the code to act better you can fix it at this level).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know that what I'm asking s not quite a trigger. I've already began to change my application level on NNN places with a variant of INSERTs with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE :) For now I will stick to what is available and compatible. Hope in future versions MySQL implement RULEs too.

Answer (score 1):

No. An update trigger fires once for each row that gets updated, not once for each update command that's executed. There's no way to make the trigger fire if nothing is updated. You would need to handle this in your application by checking the number of updated rows returned by your query.

Comment: Yes, these are exaclty my fears comming true :( It will most likely be impossible. That's too pity, because it would be convenient clearing out this kind of boring logic out of your application level. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If name has a unique index on it you can use `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (idiotism,name) VALUES ( 5,'Pencho');
```

Comment: Yes, `name` is unique index. I didnt know about this "REPLACE" thing. Thank you. I will try this approach in future.